# Create a set column with database migration in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration

I need to add a new column to my users table in the database. I want the type of the column to be set. The column represents the users gender. There should be two options to the set. One form Male "m" and the other for Female "f".

But I haven't found any documentation for adding a column with the set type.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What db is used? mysql? If you're want to use SET datatype, you'll have to do it manually, as rails doesn't support it. However, I'd do just

```
t.string :gender, :limit => 1
```

for the sake of convenience.

Answer (score 3):

In your Users model, you should add the following line to require M/F answers.

```
validates_inclusion_of :gender, :in => %w( m f M F)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to add the gender column with a default datatype (correct me if I'm wrong), If so there would be the step

here I'm assuming 'M' is for male and "F" is for female (you can use integers also if you wish)

create a migration

```
ruby script/generate migration add_gender_column_to_users
```

This will create a migration for you and as the name implies it will add a gender column to your users table

in your migrations self.up action add this

```
add_column :users, :gender, :string, :default => 'm'
```

here it says we are adding a gender column of string type and its default values is 'm'

and add this to self.down events

```
remove_column :users, :gender
```

so your final migration will look something like this

```
class AddGenderColumnToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :gender, :string, :default => 'm'
  end
  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :gender
  end
end
```

and do a

```
rake db:migrate
```

thats it, hope this helps